# How to make Azure Service Bus Explorer Save the connection?

Tags: azureservicebus, service-bus-explorer

I created a connection & clicked Save button, the connection works fine. but when I close & reopen the service bus explorer, my connection is gone, I have to recreate the connection.

is there a way to keep my connection?

[image]

Comment: Under `View`-->`Options`, what's used to save your settings?

Comment: Application Configuration File is being used.

Comment: When you save the settings, do you see those in `ServiceBusExplorer.exe.Config`?
Running from a local drive should save the updates to the configuration file. If it's not working for you, raise an issue at https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer/issues

Comment: thx @SeanFeldman, issue is fixed by using Run As Administrator, I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run as administrator can fix the issue, when adding a new connection. Normal usage does need the administrator's right.

took a closer look at my log file, found the cause.

```
Exception: An error occurred loading a configuration file: Access to the path 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\ServiceBusExplorer\tools\fpzwbghk.tmp' is denied.
```

I used Chocolatey to install the Service Bus Explorer.